# How to transpose a table from a wide format to narrow, using the values as a filter?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I get a table `X` (with 1 row):

```
COL_XA   COL_VG   COL_LF  COL_EQ COL_PP COL_QM ... 
  1        0        0       0      1      1
```

Each column `COL_x` can have only values 0 or 1.

I want to transform this table into this form `Y`:

```
NAME
"COL_XA"
"COL_PP"
"COL_QM"
...
```

This table should print only those columns from table `X` that the first (and only) row has value 1.

This question is related to any other question about transposition, with the difference that I don't want the actual values, but the column names, which are not known in advance.

I could use Excel or PL/SQL to create a list of strings of the form
`MIN(CASE WHEN t.COL_XA = 1 THEN 'COL_XA' ELSE null END) as NAME`, but this solution is inefficient (`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`) and difficult to maintain. And the string passed to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is limited to 32700 characters, which can be easily exceeded in production, where the table `X` can have well over 500 fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completly automate the query you must be able to read the column names of the actual cursor. In PL/SQL this is possible using DBMS_SQL (other way would be in JDBC). Based on [this OTN thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/702648) here a basic table function.

The importent parts are

1) *dbms_sql.parse* the query given as a text string and *dbms_sql.execute* it

2) *dbms_sql.describe_columns* to get the list of the column names returned from the query on table x

3) *dbms_sql.fetch_rows* to fetch the first row

4) loop the columns and checking the *dbms_sql.column_value* if equals to 1 output column_name (with PIPE)

```
 create or replace type str_tblType as table of varchar2(30);
 /

 create or replace function get_col_name_on_one  return  str_tblType
 PIPELINED
 as
  l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  l_columnValue   varchar2(2000);
  l_columnOutput  varchar2(4000);
  l_status        integer;
  l_colCnt        number default 0;
  l_colDesc       dbms_sql.DESC_TAB; 
 begin
     dbms_sql.parse( l_theCursor,  'SELECT * FROM X', dbms_sql.native );
     for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
          begin
               dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i,
                                       l_columnValue, 2000 );
               l_colCnt := i;
           exception
              when others then
                  if ( sqlcode = -1007 ) then exit;
                  else
                       raise;
                  end if;
         end;          
      end loop;   
      dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, 1, l_columnValue, 2000 );
      l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);  
      dbms_sql.describe_columns(l_theCursor,l_colCnt, l_colDesc);

      if dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 then
      for lColCnt in 1..l_colCnt
      loop
         dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, lColCnt, l_columnValue );
         --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_columnValue);
         IF (l_columnValue = '1') THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Upper(l_colDesc(lColCnt).col_name));
            pipe row(Upper(l_colDesc(lColCnt).col_name));
         END IF;   
      end loop;
      end if; 
 return;
 end;
 /

 select * from table(get_col_name_on_one);

 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_100
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_200
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_300
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_400
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_500
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_600
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_700
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_800
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_900
 COLUMN_LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG_1000
```

You should not get in troubles with wide tables using this solution, I tested with a 1000 column tables with *long* column names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution but I have to break it in two parts

First you extract all the column names of table. I have used LISTAGG to collect column names separated by ,
I will use the output of first query in second query.

```
select listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name ) 
from user_tab_cols where upper(table_name)='X'
```

The output of above query will be like COL_XA,COL_VG,COL_LF,COL_EQ,COL_PP,COL_QM ... and so on.

Copy above output and use in below query replacing

```
select NAME from X
unpivot ( bit for NAME in (<outputvaluesfromfirstquery>))
where bit=1
```

I am trying to merge above two, but I have option for pivot xml but not for unpivot xml.

Comment: Thank you. I think I cannot afford any manual intervention in the process, but it feels like a step in good direction.

Comment: Even I was thinking of `UNPIVOT`. What does `bit` signify here?

Comment: Bit is the column name assigned to values in the row which is 0 or 1 in your case. Its just a name. You can change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a bunch of `union all`s:

```
select 'COL_XA' as name from table t where col_xa = 1 union all
select 'COL_VG' as name from table t where col_vg = 1 union all
. . .
```

EDIT:

If you have only one row, then you do not need:

```
 MIN(CASE WHEN t.COL_XA = 1 THEN 'COL_XA' ELSE null END) as NAME
```

You can simply use:

```
(CASE WHEN t.COL_XA = 1 THEN 'COL_XA' END)
```

The `MIN()` isn't needed for one row and the `ELSE null` is redundant.

Comment: I know. But I would need to find a way to overcome the 32k limit on `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Do you have any idea how? Remember, that I don't know in advance the column names.

Comment: Depending on the length of the table name, the above should be ok.  You do not need the `as name` on each row.

Comment: you can get the list of column names from `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`   table @AdamRyczkowski

Comment: @MahendarMahi I know where I can get the column names from. The question is: how to write the query in such a way, that it will work for any table (with the given name as a parameter).